# How to align 4 different form elements

Tags: html, css

This is one of the tricky css things

I have 4 elements in a navbar, and I want join 3 of them them into one beautiful searchbox. The idea is to have all the searchbox with the same height, alignment and cheek by jowl. In the other hand the the link must be appropriately positioned.

I've tried it all, and I can make it work for one navigator but not for 2 of them, which isn't ok.

Here is the html example:

```
<a href="#" id="btn-category">Comprar por Categoría ▼</a>
<select>
 <option>a</option>
 <option>b</option>
</select>
<input type="text">
<input type="submit">
```

and the base css:

```
#btn-category{
 font-size: 8pt;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 80px;
}

input, select{
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px;
 font-size: 10pt;
 height: 30px;
}

select{
 font-size: 8pt;
}
```

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Q7Ge4/1/

Only to make it clear, **it's about the height** of the search box elements... something like the ebay search box

Comment: So many ways to do this, What do you want? i would suggest `divs` (inline)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/HdeUc/)

```
#btn-category {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  font-size: 11px;
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
}
input:focus,
select:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #12b6f3;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 #12b6f3;
}
select,
input {
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
select {
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 8pt;
}
input[type="text"] {
  height: 18px;
  width: 150px;
  transition: width 0.4s linear;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
  width: 200px;
}
input[type="submit"] {
  width: 70px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, regrettably css still being very complex for such a simple task. Greetings and thanks

Comment: I try to clean the CSS ;)

Comment: I cleaned CSS a little and updated the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/HdeUc/)

Comment: Just to make it clear the solution for people with the same question... The trick is in the "clear" css property.

Answer (score 1):

All that we would do, is something like to place the content of form in one `div` and then use `display: inline;` for that div! Here is the code:

```
<div class="form">
<a href="#" id="btn-category">Comprar por Categoría ▼</a>
  <select>
    <option>a</option>
    <option>b</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</div>
```

The trick here will be to show the elements placed inside the div in a line! As the one in the fiddle. It will be done with this code:

```
.form {
display: inline;
}
```

That's it! With this, all the elements inside that div will be displayed in one line. And the `select`, `input[type="text"]` and `input[type="submit"]` will all be in one line!

**The height thing:**

The height thing in `select` or `input` is added via `padding: something;` you can use this:

```
select, input[type="text"], input[type="submit"] {
padding: 10px;
}
```

This is whats been done there, **note:** you cannot use `height` in inputs!

Comment: it's not about the alignment itself but about the height... see the example fiddle

Comment: Yes... I noted that, but the elements (select vs input) simply doesn't remain totally aligned using padding

Comment: Then there might be an issue with the height of that div! When the elements' have height value height than div, then there come's the issue of non-aligning! I don't know where you are missing. Please show me some code.

Comment: You can but it does not work properly using the same height on several elements

Comment: Well, then you can use something like: `select { padding: 10px; } input[type="text"] { padding: 5px }` something like that!